# Fill textbox when selected something in dropdownlist in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textbox, drop-down-menu

I am implementing in Ruby On Rails, and I want that when I change the selection of the dropdownlist, a textbox is filled with a value. In my case, I have a dropdown with repositories and the textbox is filled with the hostname. But this does not really matter.

How can i become this? I searched the internet but doesn't find anything good.

This is my dropdown and textbox:
dropdown is made with a helper:

```
<%= scm_select_tag(@repository) %> 
<%= text_field_tag 'repository_url'%>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript

In my solution, the textbox will be filled with the option you selected

```
// in application.js using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id_for_scm_select_tag").change(function() {
    $("#id_for_scm_select_tag option:selected").map(function() {
      $("#id_for_text_field_tag").val($(this).text());
    });
  });
});
```

And I can't help but show you how this would look in the more concise Coffeescript

```
// in application.js.coffee using jQuery
$ ->
  $("#id_for_scm_select_tag").change ->
    $("#id_for_scm_select_tag option:selected").map ->
      $("#id_for_text_field_tag").val($(this).text())
```

Comment: And how give I the id for the elements?

Comment: Can't I put this JQuery in the view? How would this look like then?

Comment: the id for the element replaces the #id_for_scm_select_tag and #id_for_text_field_tag in the source code. You need not put this in the view but if you want to, wrap it in `<script>` tags